# How to get Simple product Customizable Options in a phtml file

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options, custom, phtml, simple-product

How to get a simple product Customizable option value and key in a .phtml file using product id or Sku Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the following code snippet to get custom product  option by loading product Id :

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Load product by product id
        $productObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')
                ->create()->load($product_id)->getOptions();
        foreach ($productObject as $o) {
            foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
                $value->getData();
            } 
        }
```

By this code you will get custom option in phtml .

Answer (score 2):

```
/** @var CheckoutSession */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
 */
public function __construct(Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

public function execute() {

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote  */
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote(); //here you will get quote data
    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems(); 
    foreach($items as $item) {
      echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
      echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
      echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
      echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
      echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';

      $productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
      if (isset($productOptions['options'])) {
        foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value) {
            $optionType = $value['option_type'];
            echo 'optionType: '.$optionType.'<br />';
        }
     }

      echo "<br />";            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Prince Patel